ValueError when Integrating with Sympy
I'm trying to do integration using sympy as follows.
from sympy import integrate, symbols
x = symbols('x')
integrate(x**(3/2) * (x-1/2), (x,0,1))

But I'm getting the following error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[4], line 3
      1 from sympy import symbols, integrate
      2 x = symbols('x')
----> 3 integrate(x**(3/2) * (x-1/2), (x,0,1))

ValueError: Non-suitable parameters.


What am I doing wrong?

This is a bug. https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/26956

When using SymPy, it is always advisable to use exact numbers instead of floating point numbers. If you rewrite your expression to use Rational instead of floats, the integration succeeds:
integrate(x**Rational(3, 2) * (x-Rational(1, 2)), (x,0,1))
# out: 3/35


I don't rightly know why, but the solver can't handle the combination of the form x**(3/2) * (x-1/2), but if you expand it to x**(5/2) - 0.5*x**(3/2), it works:
from sympy import integrate, symbols
x = symbols('x')
integrate(x**(5/2) - 0.5*x**(3/2), x)

Or, with a fraction:
from sympy import integrate, symbols, s
x = symbols('x')
integrate(x**(5/2) - S(1)/2*x**(3/2), x)


If you put your symbols in a parenthesis, you should not multiply the compound value with another symbol again in a way that symbol becomes multiplied to an integer. In other words, you should write the simplest equation in respect to the symbols. in your example this works by removing the parenthesis for the second argument:
from sympy import integrate, symbols
x = symbols('x')
integrate(x**(3/2) * x-1/2, x)

which prints:

But if you meant, as I suspect, x to the power of 3/2 multiplied to (x-1/2). then below is the right equation:
from sympy import integrate, symbols
x = symbols('x')
x**(3/2)*x -(1/2)*(x**(3/2))

which gives:

Pay careful attention to parenthesis, especially for the power values, for example x**3/2 means  while x**(3/2) means .
Good luck to you all.
